# Selenium ProfilesIni Not Working with geckodriver.exe / Selenium Server 3.0.0

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

So I updated to Selenium Server Standalone 3.0.0 and as (quite irritatingly) the Firefox Webdriver is not included anymore and you have to manually install the geckodriver.exe. And now Webdriver is not loading my firefox profile, and not throwing an error. The default profile is being loaded not my custom profile.

So my code went from this:

```
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("TestABProfile");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

To this:

```
    File file = new File("%testpath%\\Modules\\geckodriver-v0.10.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("TestABProfile");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

which would seem like it is a problem with the geckodriver.exe.

Additional info:
The custom profile name is correct.
A breakpoint on the ProfilesIni line shows that my custom profile IS being found. It is just not being loaded in the next line.

BTW, why am I having to reference this geckos.e
Please help fix this geckodriver.exe now, with the new (not so very 'stand alone') Selenium Server???

Thanks!